# How can I make a redirect in the Drogon framework of the C++ language?

Tags: c++, redirect, frameworks

Redirect is being the analog of redirect. For example, in [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29) ([Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)) - redirect(URL), where URL is a string, a link to enter another page or website. How to make it in [Drogon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drogon_(software)), if is possible?

<sub>I don't catch information about it.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this script works: "window.location.href = "/";" as well as this method req->path()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    callback(drogon::HttpResponse::newRedirectionResponse(newURL));
```